# Running a solver equation function in Python

Tags: python, calculation

I'm trying to run this function in order to solve equations of the form `f(f(....(f(x))) = x` and this is my python code :

```
from sympy import * 
x=symbols('x')

def give_list(x1):
    P,Q=x**2-1,x
    l=[]
    for k in range(x1):
        print(x1)
        U=P/Q
        P,Q=P.simplify(),Q.simplify()
        eqn = U - 1/U - x
        l+=(Poly(eqn.as_numer_denom()[0]).nroots(n=4))
        P,Q=P**2-Q**2,P*Q
        P,Q=P.simplify(),Q.simplify()
    return l
print(len(give_list(24)))
```

I got this errors :

```
24
24
24
24
24
24
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\polytools.py", line 3649, in nroots
    roots = mpmath.polyroots(coeffs, maxsteps=maxsteps,
  File "C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mpmath\calculus\polynomials.py", line 195, in polyroots
    raise ctx.NoConvergence("Didn't converge in maxsteps=%d steps." \
mpmath.libmp.libhyper.NoConvergence: Didn't converge in maxsteps=50 steps.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\PE729.py", line 66, in <module>
    print(len(give_list(24)))
  File "C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\PE729.py", line 62, in give_list
    l+=(Poly(eqn.as_numer_denom()[0]).nroots(n=4))
  File "C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\polytools.py", line 3657, in nroots
    raise NoConvergence(
mpmath.libmp.libhyper.NoConvergence: convergence to root failed; try n < 4 or maxsteps > 50
```

N.B: i can't reduce n anymore , is there another solution to run my function give_list with x1 = 24

Comment: Hi again, have you tried giving a higher maxsteps? Can you state more explicitly what equation you are trying to solve?

Comment: I would like to raise the value of n ( n = 4 is less for precision for me  )  , no i didn't try to change maxsetps ( i don't know where to change it in the code ) , the problem is : given f(x) = x-1/x , i would like to solve f(f(x) = x , f(f(f(x)) = x , f(f(f(f(x))) = x, etc

Comment: Hmm that's odd. Say you have an `x` with `f(x)=x` it should follow that f(f(f(x)))=f(f(x))=f(x)=x right? So why not just solve f(x)=x?

Comment: `maxsteps` is a keyword argument to `nroots`. By default it is 50 so it does 50 steps to get closer to the solution and if what it has then isn't close enough it raises an error.

Comment: Yes the function is odd , but f(x)=x don't have solutions , on the other hand , f(f(f(x))=x give me solutions , i don't understand your reasoning

Answer (score 0):

This solves `f(f(....(f(x))) = x` for `f(x) = x-1/x` numerically as you said in the comments is what you are trying to do.

## Version 1: Is guaranteed to find all solutions but is relatively slow.

```
from sympy import * 

x=symbols('x')

def repeat(func, n):
    def new_func(x):
        for _ in range(n):
            x = func(x)
        return x
    return new_func


def f(x):
    return x-1/x 

for n in range(2, 7):
    eqn = repeat(f,n)(x)-x
    print(n, Poly(eqn.as_numer_denom()[0]).nroots())
```

This just works for me and gives:

```
2 [-0.707106781186548, 0.707106781186548]
3 [-1.46190220008154, -0.777861913430206, -0.507713305942872, 0.507713305942872, 0.777861913430206, 1.46190220008154]
4 [-1.98904379073655, -1.48628965095479, -1.30656296487638, -0.813473286151600, -0.707106781186548, -0.541196100146197, -0.415823381635519, 0.415823381635519, 0.541196100146197, 0.707106781186548, 0.813473286151600, 1.30656296487638, 1.48628965095479, 1.98904379073655]
5 [-2.41545660696940, -2.00145620757714, -1.85510188820248, -1.50181999459672, -1.41914220567326, -1.31604793846555, -1.24172627706540, -0.835961234160827, -0.774521517521973, -0.714491187612963, -0.685106200482040, -0.556197198403633, -0.516598196232952, -0.436395812155433, -0.360266484465194, 0.360266484465194, 0.436395812155433, 0.516598196232952, 0.556197198403633, 0.685106200482040, 0.714491187612963, 0.774521517521973, 0.835961234160827, 1.24172627706540, 1.31604793846555, 1.41914220567326, 1.50181999459672, 1.85510188820248, 2.00145620757714, 2.41545660696940]
6 [-2.78239673626141, -2.42299435953793, -2.29516266137635, -2.01028188414005, -1.93777043407717, -1.85946369466332, -1.80193773580484, -1.51283920812063, -1.46190220008154, -1.42171343247665, -1.40177496925008, -1.32167422188684, -1.29342081368380, -1.24697960371747, -1.20467134431239, -0.851830427655270, -0.810422925121491, -0.777861913430206, -0.764263390941947, -0.718336804559465, -0.707106781186548, -0.688393704827180, -0.673767837236344, -0.565058118281228, -0.544186041350644, -0.520277232398841, -0.507713305942872, -0.445041867912629, -0.423500707838532, -0.374569420894612, -0.322112140647414, 0.322112140647414, 0.374569420894612, 0.423500707838532, 0.445041867912629, 0.507713305942872, 0.520277232398841, 0.544186041350644, 0.565058118281228, 0.673767837236344, 0.688393704827180, 0.707106781186548, 0.718336804559465, 0.764263390941947, 0.777861913430206, 0.810422925121491, 0.851830427655270, 1.20467134431239, 1.24697960371747, 1.29342081368380, 1.32167422188684, 1.40177496925008, 1.42171343247665, 1.46190220008154, 1.51283920812063, 1.80193773580484, 1.85946369466332, 1.93777043407717, 2.01028188414005, 2.29516266137635, 2.42299435953793, 2.78239673626141]
```

## Version 2: This is comparably much much faster but can miss solutions.

The approach is to partition the search interval into steps of 10^-6 and check if the sign of f_n(x)-x has changed during the steps. If so feed it to a solver finding the zero.

One problem that can occur with this approach is that `f_n(x)-x` has a zero but no sign change. This can happen see e.g. the zero of `f(x)=x^2` but it is reasonably unlikely. An other one is that it does change signs but we would have to check smaller intervals to detect that. I have chosen (10^-6, 20) as search interval since 20 seemed like a reasonable upper bound considering the solutions for f_1,...f_6 and since f_n-x is is odd we don't need to worry about negative solutions (they are just minus the positive solutions).

One reason to be hopeful the 2nd problem doesn't occur is that this approach does find all the positive solutions to f_6 obtain by the other method.

```
fn = repeat(f,25)

epsilon = 1e-6
test_values = np.arange(0+epsilon,20,epsilon)
value_positive = fn(test_values) > 0
sign_change = (~value_positive[:-1])&(value_positive[1:])

@np.vectorize
def find_root(a,b):
    return optimize.root_scalar(fn, bracket=(a,b)).root

find_root(test_values[:-1][sign_change],test_values[1:][sign_change])
```

Giving:

```
array([0.14548, 0.15015535, 0.15314301, ..., 6.52984421, 6.65976928,
       6.87379705])
```

Comment: It stop at n=6 , after that it will take too much to run , it very slow if i want to reach n = 25 for example

Comment: @meh98 I have added a solution that works with n=25